# libgdx - box2d velocity and forces not working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I have a very simple LibGDX game that uses Box2d. Right now, it is just a ship that moves around on a map. I can make the ship move with keyboard controls if I use the        `body.setTransform()` method to change the ship's location, but that obviously does not take advantage of the capabilities of Box2d. I want to control the player ship using the `applyForce()` method, but that method for some reason does not do anything, no matter how high or low I set the force. I also tried `applyLinearImpulse()` and `setLinearVelocity()`, and both had the same effect: nothing. And I confirmed through logging that my ship's velocity was in fact remaining at a constant 0.0 and not just changing by miniscule amounts.

Here's the relevant stuff from the game loop and entities:

http://pastebin.com/bsA4fVPn

The part in question particularly:

```
public void update(){
            this.applyIntendedMovement();
    }

    public void applyIntendedMovement(){
            if(this.isMovingUp){
                    this.body.applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0,100).scl(this.SPEED_FACTOR), true);
            }
    }
```

Why does the call to `applyForce()` do nothing? Also, I explicitly set a density when creating my Player body, but when I check the player's mass at any given moment, it is 0.0. I know there is a good chance these two problems are related, but I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I feel so stupid. I realized that I was setting my bodyDef to Dynamic *after* I had already created the body. I just rearranged some lines of code, and it works. Sorry folks.